# SQL: using JOINS, ANY or IN to get first, second, and third degree nodes from a source node

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables named `course`, `student` and `students_in` in a MySQL database.

The tables look like this:

**course**

```
  course_id       name
    3             Physics
   12             English
   19             Basket Weaving
    4             Computer Science
  212             Discrete Math
  102             Biology
   20             Chemistry
   50             Robotics
    7             Data Engineering
```

**student**

```
id    name
 2    Sally
 1    Bob
17    Robert
 9    Pierre
12    Sydney
41    James
22    William
 5    Mary
 3    Robert
92    Doris
 6    Harry
```

**students_in**

```
  course_id   student_id      grade
    3              2              B
  212              2              A
    3             12              A
   19             12              C
    3             41              A
    4             41              B
  212             41              F
   19             41              A
   12             41              B
    3             17              C
    4              1              A
  102              1              D
  102             22              A
   20             22              A
   20              5              B
   50              3              A
   12             92              B
   12             17              C
    7              6              A
```

Here is a Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3f991/1

My goal is to get the `id` and `name` of the students who:

1. have taken a course with Sally (i.e. "first-degree" relationship), **OR**
2. have taken a course with someone who has taken a course with Sally (i.e. "second-degree" relationship), **OR**
3. have taken a course with someone who has taken a course with someone who has taken a course with Sally (i.e. "third-relationship" relationship)

Essentially, we're looking for first-, second-, and third-degree relationships to Sally.

Here is a depiction of what this looks like logically:

[image]

Since Sally took course IDs 3 and 212, **the desired result would look like this** (not the colorful table above, which I provided for illustration of the logic involved):

```
student_id       student_name
    12           Sydney             <-- took course ID 3 with Sally
    41           James              <-- took course ID 3 and 212 with Sally
    17           Robert             <-- took course ID 3 with Sally
     1           Bob                <-- took course ID 4 with James
    92           Doris              <-- took course ID 12 with James and Robert
   102           William            <-- took course ID 102 with Bob
```

**Other than using a `recursive CTE`, is it possible to get the desired output using a more simplified approach, such as one or more of the following?**

1. `JOINS` and `subqueries`
2. using the `ANY` or `IN` operators

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but the query will be too complex.

Comment: and wouldn't be generalizable for any depth n.

Comment: One could left join to student in  3 times, one for each level and then unpivot

Answer (score 1):

Use `CTE`s for each of the levels with the operator `IN`.
Finally use `UNION` to get all the student ids (without duplicates) and again with the operator `IN` get the students details from `student`:

```
WITH 
  cte0 AS (SELECT id FROM student WHERE name = 'Sally'),
  cte1 AS (SELECT student_id FROM students_in WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id FROM students_in WHERE student_id = (SELECT id FROM cte0))),
  cte2 AS (SELECT student_id FROM students_in WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id FROM students_in WHERE student_id IN (SELECT student_id FROM cte1))),
  cte3 AS (SELECT student_id FROM students_in WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id FROM students_in WHERE student_id IN (SELECT student_id FROM cte2))),
  cte AS (SELECT student_id FROM cte1 UNION SELECT student_id FROM cte2 UNION SELECT student_id FROM cte3)
SELECT *
FROM student 
WHERE id IN (SELECT student_id FROM cte) AND id <> (SELECT id FROM cte0);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gRmH--jy).

If you want to use this solution just for comparison to a recursive query then fine, but it is obvious that this is not the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can union the separate degrees and group/order the resulting names:

```
select `name` from (
    (
    select student.`name`
    from student sally
    join students_in sally_course
    on sally.id = sally_course.student_id
    join students_in si1
    on sally_course.course_id = si1.course_id
    join student
    on si1.student_id = student.id
    where student.`name` <> 'sally'
    )
    union
    (
    select student.`name`
    from student sally
    join students_in sally_course
    on sally.id = sally_course.student_id
    join students_in si1
    on sally_course.course_id = si1.course_id
    join students_in si2
    on si1.course_id = si2.course_id
    join student
    on si2.student_id = student.id
    where student.`name` <> 'sally'
    )
    union
    (
    select student.`name`
    from student sally
    join students_in sally_course
    on sally.id = sally_course.student_id
    join students_in si1
    on sally_course.course_id = si1.course_id
    join students_in si2
    on si1.course_id = si2.course_id
    join students_in si3
    on si2.course_id = si3.course_id
    join student
    on si3.student_id = student.id
    where student.`name` <> 'sally'
    )) t
    group by `name`
    order by `name`
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'd add the recursive approach following with the two steps:

- base step: retrieves all courses which Sally participated to
- recursive step: retrieves all courses of students that have attended courses obtained at (n-1)th step

You can generalize how deep you want to go in the filtering clause of the recursive step (`WHERE recursion_depth + 1 <= <N>`).

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT s.student_id, s.course_id, 0 AS recursion_depth
    FROM       students_in s
    INNER JOIN student ON s.student_id = student.id_ 
    WHERE student.name_ = 'Sally'
  
    UNION ALL
   
    SELECT s2.student_id, s2.course_id, recursion_depth+1 
    FROM       cte
    INNER JOIN students_in s1 ON s1.course_id = cte.course_id
    INNER JOIN students_in s2 ON s1.student_id = s2.student_id
    WHERE recursion_depth + 1 <= 3
)
SELECT DISTINCT student.*
FROM       cte
INNER JOIN student ON cte.student_id = student.id_
WHERE NOT student.name_ = 'Sally'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Tu6nHvv7fTfUvxACodAn8/0).

**Note**: looking for a non-recursive query would translate to manually apply base step + recursive step number of join operations, multiplied by the depth value, thing that the DBMS would do with a recursive query in a more natural and clean way.